# PDF duplex printing not possible but Libre Writer offers duplex

Tags: pdf, printing, printer, adobe-reader, duplex

I am using

- Windows 11
- [Brother DCP-L2510D](https://www.brother.co.uk/support/dcp-l2510d/faqs/setup-settings/faq00100213_001) - that supports duplex

**I am able to print duplex** any document

- from Libre Writer
- Firefox

but not from

- Acrobat Reader nor Foxit
- Chrome

. I am not able to find duplex settings in Acrobat but in Foxit I can see duplex greyed out

[image]

Could anyone suggests how to print PDF duplex in my case?

Comment: The given Documentation tells to select specific Paper Sizes. Maybe your libre writer Document is in the Supported Size , but the PDF Document is not in the Supported Size .... (1) Try with other PDF Document. (2) Try Saving PDF from libre writer & then using Acrobat to Print that. (3) Try overriding the Paper Size to Supported Size to check whether Duplex is getting enabled.

Comment: I do not think that it is paper size related. I can print duplex from Firefox but Chrome.